# AngularJS needless span

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following HTML/AngularJS code:

```
<span ng-show="true" ng-repeat="timeRangeObject in timeRangeObjects" ng-if="ifExpression">
    <span class="progress-bar progress-bar-{{timeRangeObject.type}}" style="width: {{timeRangeObject.percentage}}%" />
</span>
```

The result of this code is:

```
<span>
    <span class="progress-bar ...
</span>
<span>
    <span class="progress-bar ...
</span>
<span>
    <span class="progress-bar ...
</span>
<span>
    <span class="progress-bar ...
</span>
```

but I would absolutely need this one:

```
<span>
    <span class="progr ...
    <span class="progr ...
    <span class="progr ...
    <span class="progr ...
</span>
```

Is there any possibility to do it like this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
<span 
    ng-repeat="timeRangeObject in timeRangeObjects" class="progress-bar progress-bar-{{timeRangeObject.type}}" style="width: {{timeRangeObject.percentage}}%" >
</span>
```

You can wrap your ng-if expression around the repeated **span** if you need it.

Answer (score 4):

Just put `ng-repeat` onto inner span. I removed the `ng-show=true` part, it is unnecessary.

```
<span ng-if="ifExpression">
    <span ng-repeat="timeRangeObject in timeRangeObjects" class="progress-bar progress-bar-{{timeRangeObject.type}}" style="width: {{timeRangeObject.percentage}}%" />
</span>
```